# Hibernate Lazy Loading with complex object Graph

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a entity structure something like

```
Class A {
    // some member data
    List<Class B>
    List<Class E>
}

Class B {
    List<Class C>
}

Class C {
    List<Class D>
}

Class E {
    List<F>
} 

//...it can be deep at any level
```

The problem is while fetching data hibernate creates proxy (persistent bags) for all lazy loaded Collectio. I give data according to user demands and it really isn't in my control how deeper data user wants in single call. What I need is to make null other other collection bags which is not demand by user cause if i don't do so, it gives me all data on POGO to DTO conversion, and if I detached it from session,it gives me Lazy Initialization Exception during mapping/JSON conversion,is there any method to make it null my entity POGO ??or do I hv to traverse it manually before passing to other level,any method /best practice ??

Thanks.in advance

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Hibernate Detach Utility

What you need is a 'Hibernate Detach Utility', like this one here:

https://github.com/ocpsoft/socialpm/blob/master/gwt/src/main/java/com/ocpsoft/socialpm/gwt/server/util/HibernateDetachUtility.java

This nulls out all uninitialized collections.

### Use the Session in View Pattern

Or you could use the so-called 'Session in View' pattern. This keeps the Hibernate session open in your 'view'. For example, if you are returning the data from a REST web service as json, the view would be the bit of code that renders the json.

### Copy Data into a Presentation Layer

Another possibility is that you traverse the object graph in your code, and copy what you want to return into a separate value object presentation layer. There may be tools that can help to automate some of this copying.

This is a popular option, but in my opinion it is a good choice. In the majority of cases the data will be presented 1:1 as it exists in the entity layer.

---

I would recommend a well configured Hibernate Detach Utility over the Session in View pattern, or the copying option.